# An npm enoent error appears when using React. I have tried everything that I can

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have been using the react tutorial of freecodecamp and I'm still stuck in the first step of using react. It appears that error of nmp enoent when I make my first app . I have used everything I have read on the internet but nothing seems to help. At the same time I realized that localhost:3000 doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error, you need to –

- Close all the open terminal windows.
  Even of other projects.
- Restart the Metro bundler.

You may also check if you are using the wrong folder name in terminal. Sometimes, we delete a folder and still inside that folder in terminal. That will create issues. So, leave that folder and enter again. For example –

```
cd .. && cd folder_name
```